# SSRS 2008: Create URL link to pdf file on file server for each cell in report table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working on an SSRS 2008 r2 Report, I have a table and one of the columns contains item numbers. We have pdf files located on our file server who's file name matches these item numbers and I need to create a link for each cell in the item numbers column to the correct pdf file.

I can access the pdf files on our file server in two ways.

1. S:\Production\Drawings\pdf file
2. \server_name\drive_name\Production\Drawings\pdf file

The file names for the pdf files is *item_number*.pdf and in my SSRS report the name of the DataSet field for the item number is *item*

In the action expression for the item number Text Box Properties, how can I tell SSRS that for row one open file *S:\Production\Drawings\2-50010.pdf* and for row two open *S:\Production\Drawings\8-8010.pdf* and etc...

This report when run, will render to MHTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an expression for the Hyperlink in your action.

```
="S:\Production\Drawings\"+Fields!item.Value+".pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this not to open a file, but a shared folder, so the user could traverse scanned images in that folder. Everything was bombing out until I realised my SQL pulled a lot of records for which I did not have a folder.

`="S:\MyScanPath\\"+Fields!.MyPathColumnName.Value`    works fine when it produces a valid path.