# SQL SSRS Open Docx files from Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I've got an issue which I just can't get my head around.

I'm trying to create an SSRS report which shows all documents linked to the person and are clickable/openable via clicking on the filename within the table.

Now the first part I have done, I can show a report with all documents grouped. But I can't figure out how to have the documents clickable with an action to open them up.

I have looked at doing a Drillthrough, and have tested by using the below expression

```
="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test.docx"
```

But even this won't open. Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Tools:
SQL Server 2018
Visual Studio

Comment: When asking SQL _language_ questions, [mcve] is a great start. (Note that the <sql> tag has "_If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._".)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS 2008: Create URL link to pdf file on file server for each cell in report table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389538/ssrs-2008-create-url-link-to-pdf-file-on-file-server-for-each-cell-in-report-ta)

Comment: And beware of using user-specific directories generally. Why would the "server" know anything about a "user" and their account-specific directories when that user might be accessing SSRS from anywhere?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that //file: links links no longer work with modern browsers. This might only be the case using a NC path though, I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Edge browser, I am able to get to network folders using the Go to URL with a File link.

```
="file:\\server\folder\subfolder\Test.txt"
```

And I was able to get into a local folder.

```
="file:C:\Users\Public\desktop.ini"
```

This will probably depend on permissions.